# Ubuntu 20.04 webcam not detected on Asus Zenbook UX4330U

Tags: asus, webcam, 20.04

I've a problem detecting webcam after upgrade from 19.10 yo 20.04, webcam is not listed in available video devices

```
nano@nano-notebook:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:15.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

nano@nano-notebook:~$ ls -ltrh /dev/video*

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 abr 24 23:57 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 abr 24 23:57 /dev/video0
```

nano@nano-notebook:~$ ls -ltrh /dev/video*

```
ls: no se puede acceder a '/dev/video*': No existe el archivo o el directorio
```

nano@nano-notebook:~$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices

```
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.
```

Do anyone now the default drivers package, or how to solve this?

Already change grub to :
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pcie_aspm=force quiet splash"